# How do I get intellij IDEA to highlight assignment?

Tags: intellij-idea

The only options I have seen only highlight where the variable is accessed but not where it's assigned or declared.

Edit:
On Windows 10 editing Java code.

I'm already using [image]

But if I put the cursor on a usage, it doesn't highlight the assignments above.
[image]

Comment: Are you using "Find Usages"?

Comment: @DavidCullen If that's a setting, then yes, and like I said, it only highlights usages, i.e. accesses but not assignments or declarations of that variable. If that's a name of a plugin, then no.

Comment: What operating system are you using? The keyboard shortcuts are different for each. What language are you editing?

Comment: @DavidCullen I've added some screenshots with my editor settings an example of what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a feature of the Colors Scheme.
Under *Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General* you can change the settings for *Code > Identifier under caret (write)*, which will be any assignment operation to the variable you currently have selected with the caret.
Here you can set not only the background color (for highlighting), but also a color stripe on the scroll bar or other text effects:

[image]

Comment: This is it, thanks! This has been driving me nuts ever since I switched to Intellij from Eclipse and had me considering going back. Now it's just baffling why those check boxes for "Identifier under caret" would have been defaulted to unchecked.